# #if IOS compiler directive doesn't appear to be working

Tags: maui, visual-studio-2022

I have the following code in place:

```
private static MauiAppBuilder RegisterFirebaseServices(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events => {
#if IOS
        events.AddiOS(iOS => iOS.FinishedLaunching((app, launchOptions) => {
            CrossFirebase.Initialize(app, launchOptions);
            return false;
        }));
#else
        events.AddAndroid(android => android.OnCreate((activity, state) =>
            CrossFirebase.Initialize(activity, state)));
#endif
    });

    builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => CrossFirebaseAuth.Current);
    return builder;
}
```

On the VS2022 toolbar, I have Android-Pixel 5 selected as where I want to run it.

In the past when I've used compiler directives and I change where the app is to be run, the code will gray out the inactive code and "activate" the code that is in the type of play.

However, with Pixel5 selected, the #if IOS ... code is selected and the else is grayed out.

Anyone know what may be causing this to happen?

Comment: When MSVS makes "wrong assumptions" such as these, it's an Intellisense bug. Meaning, it's displayed wrong, but not compiled wrong. Are you having actual issues when compiling or is it just a visual hinderence?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to compile it yet...

Comment: @JonSkeet The IOS code in this case should be grayed out though since I have the android selected...

Comment: @Zonus: Yes, apologies, I misread. Will try to reproduce in my own MAUI app. Although as TheNomad says, you may well find that once you've gone through an initial successful compilation, it just works.

Comment: Okay, I've just somewhat reproduced it. It looks like VS not really keeping up somehow. Try putting your cursor at the end of `#if IOS`, press space and then backspace (ending up with the same text).

Comment: that doesn't seem to do it for me...  Still stuck on the IOS code

Comment: I removed the code that was causing issues in the compile (it was in the #if IOS section) and replaced it with something that would.  After compiling the issue persists...

Comment: Humbug. I would check next whether it's just a display issue or actual compiler behavior - if you put `#error` into the IOS part, does it break the build?

Comment: I reverted a version back just to see if there was something that was introduced and it's still there, and yes, if I put an #error in the #if IOS section it won't compile.  To add even more on this, if I do a #if IOS...#endif then #if ANDROID ... #endif then both code sections are active... =O

Comment: I created a new .net maui program and it appears to be working.  I'm thinking my app has some corruption on it, I added a package that was supposed to be compatible but it loaded some packages that caused issues.  I had a heck of a time removing them.  But I did revert the code to a version prior to that... Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Look at upper-left of source code pane, where it shows which project you are examining source for. (This is independent of which target you choose to build/run.) This is what controls intellisense.

Comment: Bingo.  It's showing IOS even though I have the pixel selected!  What is going on?